# What does "Am I sick?" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, sinclair-lewis, main-street

I would like to know what "Am I sick?" means in the following sentences:

> “I mustn't! I mustn't! I'm nervous this afternoon. **Am I sick?** . . .
>   Good Lord, I hope it isn't that! Not now! How people lie! How these
>   stories lie! They say the bride is always so blushing and proud and
>   happy when she finds that out, but—I'd hate it! I'd be scared to death!
>   Some day but——Please, dear nebulous Lord, not now! Bearded sniffy
>   old men sitting and demanding that we bear children. If THEY had to
>   bear them——! I wish they did have to! Not now! Not till I've got hold
>   of this job of liking the ash-pile out there! . . . I must shut up. I'm
>   mildly insane. I'm going out for a walk. I'll see the town by myself.
>   My first view of the empire I'm going to conquer!”

- [Sinclair Lewis, *Main Street*, Chapter 4](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/543/543-h/543-h.htm#link2HCH0004)

Carol and Kennicott, the newly married, enjoyed their honeymoon trip in Colorado mountains and now arrived at their new home in Gopher Prairie, Kennicott's hometown. But as soon as they arrived, Carol was deeply disappointed at the town's ugliness and the house's dismalness. Nevertheless, she ceaselessly tried to liven herself up, but when she looked out the window towards the ash pile at the back of the church, she finally gave way.

In this part, I wonder whether the expression "sick" here literally means that she was ill (from tiredness or whatever), or that she suffered from hyperemesis, since she was talking about bearing children in this text.
But I could not be sure whether "sick" could mean "hyperemesis" in itself, and was worried that it might be my overinterpretation, so I wanted to ask you.

I would very much appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She says,

> Good lord I hope it is not "that"

If she were casually sick, why would she refer the sickness as that? she should be talking about the sickness that comes with pregnancy. The discussion further about children and childbearing only confirms that.

> They say the bride is always so blushing and proud and happy when she
>   finds  that out, but—I'd hate it!

Why would a bride blush about sickness unless it is pregnancy?